# Is it the Sanhedrin's business to look for witness after Jesus was taken into custody as is obviously the case in Matthew 26:59?

Tags: matthew

Why was the Sanhedrin's charge against Jesus not stated before he was tried? Is that the right legal practice during Jesus time?

Matthew 26:59-60 ASV

Now the chief priests and the whole council sought false witness against Jesus, that they might put him to death. But they did not find any, though many false witnesses came forward. Finally two came forward

Comment: It was hurried. A trial at night was illegal. They were rushing before Passover.

Comment: The charge was known to everyone. They may have formally announced the charge as we doo today, it is irrelevant, not all details are written descriptively. Perhaps you should ask that in Judaism se concerning the details of the judicial process.

Comment: It was this and many, many other details of Jesus' trial were illegal under Jewish law.

Comment: If you ask this on Judaism, remove Jesus references. Make it hypothetical

Answer (score 2):

Witnesses were the ones who would bring charges so yes, it would be the Sanhedrin's business to secure witnesses -- but not false witnesses, of course. The text does not state whether or not the charge against Jesus was stipulated before he was tried. Nor do we know how the reporter came to know the details of the trial. However, Sanhedrin members were judges, not prosecutors. The charges were made by the [witnesses not the judges](https://christ.org/history-rituals/the-illegal-trial-of-christ/).

In Matthew's account, Jesus was eventually charged with blasphemy: 'Then the high priest tore his clothes, saying, “He has spoken blasphemy!" But if the council was trying to find a basis to put him to death, they would need a capital crime under Roman law. Jesus' attack on the moneychangers, coupled with his claim of Messiahship  provided them a basis for this, even without "false witnesses." In any case, the accounts of these witnesses are not included, so we do not know what charges they brought. [*see comment by @Mr. Bond for a correction here.*]

Moreover, the statement that "the whole council" sought false witnesses against Jesus cannot be correct, since we know that Joseph of Arimathea was a secret disciple (John 19:38), and Nicodemus had himself defended Jesus in the Sanhedrin (John 7:50). Either these two supporters were not present, or else the report is wrong that the entire council had decided ahead of time to convict Jesus.

In any case, the trial as described was clearly illegal, because it was held at night with virtually no notice. In the Talmud, Sanhedrin 32a reads: 'In cases of capital law, the court judges during the daytime, and concludes the deliberations and issues the ruling only in the daytime...'

The [Jewish Encyclopedia states](https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/8616-jesus-of-nazareth):

> There could be no question of anything corresponding to a trial taking place on this occasion before the Sanhedrin... It is more probable that the twenty-three members of the priestly
> section [the Sadducees]... who had most reason to be offended with Jesus'
> action in cleansing the Temple, met informally after he had been
> seized... His
> claims or pretensions to the Messiahship... would be
> regarded by them as rebellion against Rome. Nothing corresponding to a
> Jewish trial took place, though it was by the action of the priests
> that Jesus was sent before Pontius Pilate.

**Given the gross illegality of the proceeding as described in Matthew's gospel, we should not be surprised if charges were not formally announced prior to its beginning. The court would indeed seek out witnesses, both for and against the defendant.**

Comment: Since those in charge of the trial  knew all the previous accusations and allegations  against Jesus, and, if they really understood Jesus correctly and that their accusation were true,  shouldn't this be the moment to prove that all their accusations were just?

Comment: In a sense the accusations were true, but not just. Jesus did disrupt Temple commerce right after he accepted the crowd's Hosannas to him as "Son of David," a messianic title. This constituted evidence that he intended to make himself the King of the Jews. Not that I think it was right for him to be turned over to Rome, only that he did accept the messianic title during his Triumphal Entry, followed immediately by a violent demonstration that struck at the economic foundation of the Temple.

Comment: @DanFefferman Actually if you read the trial record at Matthew 26:60-61 two witnesses came forward stating Jesus said, "I am able to destroy this Temple of God and rebuild it in three days." This event happened three years ago and a minimum of two witnesses is required. To the Sanhedrin Jesus belittled the temple and made it unimportant proving in their mind Jesus was blaspheming. What's important is why did Caiaphas ask Jesus to swear if He was (1) the Messiah/Christ and (2) the Son of God? Jesus said, "Yes, I am." Why is this blasphemy to claim to be the Messiah and to be the Son of God?

Comment: thanks for the correction. Claiming to be the Messiah is not blasphemy. Claiming to the the son of God is debatable depending on whether in implies divinity.

Comment: "Claiming to be the Messiah is not blasphemy." Just wrong. Claiming falsely to be the Christ most certainly is blasphemy, and this is why the Sanhedrin lose their *blank* after Jesus says it. Note "the Christ, the son of God" is routinely paired in the NT - the two terms are co-referents. Cf. Ps. 2.

Comment: I should have said "claiming to be the Messiah as Christians understand the term." Jews did not understand the messiah to be a divine being.

Comment: @DanFefferman Define "divine". The Christ was divinely ordained, and would sit at the right hand of Yahweh. He would be a unique 'son' of God.

Comment: Divine in this case means a unique  incarnation of God. You can have the last word, unless you want to move this to chat.

Answer (score 2):

The trial of Jesus the Nazarene [Sanhedrin 43a:20] clearly violated the law of [Sanhedrin 35a:10] since it took place during Eve of Pesach.

[Sanhedrin 35a.10] **Trials Prohibited on Eve of Shabbat/Pesach**

> "The Gemara explains: It is because it is not possible to conduct the trial on the eve of Shabbat or the eve of a Festival. As, how should we act? If we say that we should judge him on Shabbat eve and conclude his verdict on Shabbat eve, perhaps we would see a reason to find the accused liable, and in this situation the court is required to perform a suspension of the trial until the following day, as the court may not issue a verdict in cases of capital law on the same day as the deliberations. If we say: We should judge him on Shabbat eve and conclude the verdict on Shabbat, and, if he is found liable, kill him on Shabbat, that cannot be done, as the murder of one liable to receive court-imposed capital punishment does not override Shabbat. And if we say: We should kill him at night, after the conclusion of Shabbat, that cannot be done, as we require that the capital punishment be administered facing the sun, during the daytime."
>
> (משום דלא אפשר היכי ליעבד לידייניה במעלי שבתא וליגמריה לדיניה במעלי שבתא דילמא חזו טעם לחובה ובעו למיעבד הלנת דין לדייניה במעלי שבתא וליגמריה בשבתא וליקטליה בשבתא אין רציחה דוחה את שבת וליקטליה לאורתא נגד השמש בעינן)
>
> https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.35a.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

---

[Sanhedrin 43a:20] **Trial of Jesus the Nazarene**

> "The mishna teaches that a crier goes out before the condemned man. This indicates that it is only before him, i.e., while he is being led to his execution, that yes, the crier goes out, but from the outset, before the accused is convicted, he does not go out. The Gemara raises a difficulty: But isn’t it taught in a baraita: On Passover Eve they hung the corpse of Jesus the Nazarene after they killed him by way of stoning. And a crier went out before him for forty days, publicly proclaiming: Jesus the Nazarene is going out to be stoned because he practiced sorcery, incited people to idol worship, and led the Jewish people astray. Anyone who knows of a reason to acquit him should come forward and teach it on his behalf. And the court did not find a reason to acquit him, and so they stoned him and hung his corpse on Passover eve."
>
> (וכרוז יוצא לפניו לפניו אין מעיקרא לא והתניא בערב הפסח תלאוהו לישו והכרוז יוצא לפניו מ' יום ישו יוצא ליסקל על שכישף והסית והדיח את ישראל כל מי שיודע לו זכות יבא וילמד עליו ולא מצאו לו זכות ותלאוהו בערב הפסח )
>
> https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.43a.20?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Answer (score 2):

Peter and John<sup>1</sup> both witnessed much of the mock trial of Jesus.  The leaders knew that it was necessary to have a pretense of a legal trial, but they conducted it in great secrecy so that the people would not know what was being done and come forward with their testimony exonerating Jesus.  If the people were to find out what they were doing, the Sanhedrim would be object of great indignation; their deeds would be condemned and their mission thwarted--Jesus would be liberated at the hands of the people, and honored.

While the members of the Sanhedrim council were being summoned to the meeting, Annas and Caiaphas interrogated Jesus<sup>2</sup>, trying to provoke him to make some statement which they could use against him.  They brought two charges against him by which they hoped to have sufficient evidence to condemn him at trial.  The first of these was to accuse him as a disturber of the peace who was leading a rebellion<sup>3</sup> (not an uncommon problem among the Jews in those days as it was).  If this charge could be verified, it would suffice to see him condemned before the Roman authorities.  The second charge was that he was a blasphemer<sup>4</sup>.  This charge would suffice, if proven, to see him condemned among the Jews.

Because the Sanhedrim were in the place of the prosecution for the trial, they could not themselves, as the prosecutors, serve also as witnesses.  Unable to find true witnesses<sup>5</sup>, they bribed some false witnesses<sup>6</sup> to testify with such things as that Jesus was guilty of inciting rebellion, and to say that he was seeking to establish a separate government.  But when these witnesses were called, their testimony was vague, and, upon cross-examination, they were found even to contradict themselves<sup>7</sup>.  As this witness was worthless, the Sanhedrim were forced to seek new witnesses.

As we know, they finally found two witnesses<sup>8</sup> willing to testify whose evidence was more consistent than that of the others, and by whom they managed to reach a "guilty" verdict.

### Conclusion

As prosecution for the case, the Sanhedrim would necessarily have been needing to find witnesses.  It goes without saying, however, that bribing witnesses, or securing false witnesses by fraudulent means, ought never to have been done.

---

**References**

<sup>1</sup> Matthew 26:69-75; Mark 14:54, 66-72; Luke 22:54-62; John 18:15-18, 25-27

<sup>2</sup> Matthew 26:57; Mark 14:53; John 18:13-14, 24

<sup>3</sup> Matthew 27:11; Mark 15:2; Luke 23:2-3; John 18:33-36

<sup>4</sup> Matthew 26:65; Mark 14:64

<sup>5</sup> Matthew 26:59-60; Mark 14:55

<sup>6</sup> Matthew 26:59-60

<sup>7</sup> Mark 14:57-59

<sup>8</sup> Matthew 26:60-61